# How do I setup a display for qemu, ARM on Windows?

Tags: linux, arm, raspberry-pi, qemu, windows-10

I'm working on Windows 10, Intel i7-4700MQ, 8g ram.
I'm trying to setup Qemu to emulate an ARM system so I can test some simple assembly programs.

I'm using a new pi image for a stripped down version of linux.
Qemu tells me, "Guest has not initialized the display (yet)." and then promtly throws a Microsot Visual C++ Runtime Library Runtime Error saying that the exe tried to close in an unusual way.

This picture shows what I used to start Qemu, the Qemu window, the error box, and both the stderr and stdout files from the c:\Program Files\qemu folder

[image: Qemu failing to start]

Comment: Why are you emulating a RealView PBX if you're trying to run a Raspberry Pi image? They're completely different hardware.

Comment: Well that would be good reason to crash I suppose, what machine should I be using?

Comment: I need an ARMv7 system, that's Cortex isn't it?

Comment: Some help would be appreciated, am I missing something here?  I've looked through the Qemu docs and a little thing on the Ubuntu page about how to set up Qemu but it keeps complaining that I don't have a display and often it crashes as well.  I feel like I'm missing something simple but everything I try changing flags it either doesn't change anything or just doesn't run at all.  What am I missing!